# Почему Mozilla блокирует отпарвку POST запросов?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, firefox, firefox-devtools

Отправляю данные с формы через Ajax. Скрипт взял с соседней страницы. Там всё отправляется. Здесь нет, пишет: заблокировано DevTools: http://joxi.ru/4Ak0bbksoJxM7r
В хроме всё ок.

Заголовок запроса: http://joxi.ru/a2XappJUwjxy5A
В orign и referer один и тот же сайт.

Comment: Голосую за закрытие вопроса, т.к. ссылки "протухли"

Answer (score 0):

Тут может быть два нюанса:

1. Firefox 'Cross-Origin Request Blocked'
2. Проблемы с https сертификатом.

Можно попробовать добавить:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: проверю. это всё результат того, что браузеры начинают блочить всё и всё ссылаясь на безопасность

Comment: не дало результат. я даже  <meta name="referrer" content="strict-origin-when-cross-origin">  прописывал

Answer (score 0):

Может вы включили блокировку в DevTools?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor/request_list#Blocking_specific_URLs

[image: DevTools]

Comment: нет. проверял эту опцию